# What are the odds that no bingo number will be called in sequence?

Tags: probability

Was calling bingo numbers from a preprinted card today. Noticed that no number was called in sequence, e.g. B1 was not the first number called. I checked through the list of 75 numbers and none of them were in their sequence, ie. there was no bingo ball bearing number N that was called in the Nth position. The BINGO letters are irrelevant here, you are given a list of 75 supposedly random numbers and you keep calling them until the person playing has been able to mark off all of the numbers on their card. Sometimes it can take almost 75 numbers to complete the standard bingo card. I found it odd that not one number was in its sequence position, e.g. O75 being the 75th number in the list.
This is a variation on bingo, it is played at home with bingo cards that arrive sealed and accompanied by a 75 number list. The player who gets a bingo in the fewest "balls" is the winner.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Comment: If you are talking about a [derangement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) then the chances of that are approximately $1/e$ which is (to 2 d.p) $0.37$ or $37$%.